# IE PostMessage from sandboxed iframe to parent

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a sandboxed iframe with only "allow-scripts" set, and everything else closed. In sandboxed iframe, visitor can run some custom scripts and that's why I don't want "allow-same-origin" set (would be unsafe). So I decided to use "PostMessage" to communicate between the parent and the frame.

This works in Chrome and FF but not in IE. After investigating, it seems that sandboxed iframe in IE completely disables access to `window.parent` which also disables `window.parent.contentWindow.postMessage()`. It works if I "allow-same-origin" on iframe but that is not the option in my case.

I was under impression postMessage was there to fight cross origin issues and that it's way of communication, limited to strings, was mostly enough. Chrome's and FF's behavior seem to confirm it. But IE closes sandboxed iframe (I guess also iframe from other domains) so much that even postMessage cannot be used.

I'm lost. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot delete a question I'll post an "answer". It seems question assumed something which was not true. Even if window.parent is "permission denied", `postMessage()` to it still works and I was mistaken.

What confused me was event passed to receiving end. Chrome and FF pass `event.source` as null in this case while IE passes full URL which was in my case 'https://localhost:8080'. This failed an if statement and message was not processed leading me to believe it is not sent at all.